# Geoserver DXF Extension

Tags: geoserver, dxf

I'm trying to install geoserver's DXF [extension](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/dxf/index.html) but i'm getting a wicked stack trace in my `catalina` log.

I've installed GeoServer 2.11.0 on a 2012R2 Windows Server. Everything was great...i could use GeoServer as expected. But then I copied the contents of the 
DXF extension into `...\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib` and restart tomcat...but GeoServer won't come back online. instead i get the follow stack trace.

Any ideas?

Appreciate it! :)

```
05-May-2017 16:22:21.142 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-18] org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.extensionNames bean lookup error
 org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.geoserver.wps.ppio.DXFPPIO] for bean with name 'DXFPPIO' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.5/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-dxf-wps-2.11.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geoserver/wps/ppio/CDataPPIO
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1445)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:445)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1150)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.extensionNames(GeoServerExtensions.java:211)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.extensions(GeoServerExtensions.java:126)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.extensions(GeoServerExtensions.java:133)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.bean(GeoServerExtensions.java:332)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.bean(GeoServerExtensions.java:315)
    at org.vfny.geoserver.crs.GeoserverWKTOperationFactory.getDefinitionsURL(GeoserverWKTOperationFactory.java:44)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.CoordinateOperationFactoryUsingWKT.createBackingStore(CoordinateOperationFactoryUsingWKT.java:178)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:133)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:235)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:119)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:667)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:501)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry$1.filter(FactoryRegistry.java:192)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(Unknown Source)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProviders(FactoryRegistry.java:197)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:180)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCoordinateOperationAuthorityFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:489)
    at org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener.contextDestroyed(GeoserverInitStartupListener.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4792)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5429)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1307)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:669)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geoserver/wps/ppio/CDataPPIO
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2277)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:811)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1254)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
    ... 66 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DXF extension ships with two jars, e.g.:

- gs-dxf-core-2.11.0.jar
- gs-dxf-wps-2.11.0.jar

The second is a WPS output format, which you should add only if you also have WPS installed, if you don't have WPS you should remove it from WEB-INF/lib.